# Displaying WEPopover from UIButton instead of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, popover

I am using WEPopover in my app to pop up a popover controller containg some buttons,it works when i put wepopover controller action in tabbarIteam but i need to get popover when i click UIButton.How to do this this is my barbuttonitem code for displaying popover.

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtnAccount:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.popoverController)
    {
        UIViewController *contentViewController = [[pageAccount alloc]initWithNibName:@"pageAccount" bundle:nil];
        self.popoverController = [[[popoverClass alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];
        self.popoverController.delegate = self;
        self.popoverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.navigationController.navigationBar];

        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                                       permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown) 
                                                       animated:YES];
        [contentViewController release];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popoverController = nil;
    }
}

-(IBAction)_clickbtnAccount:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.popoverController)
    {
        UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[senderButton frame]
                                                inView:@"pageAccount"
                              permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown) 
                                              animated:YES];        
    }
    else
    {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popoverController = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you don't want to display a `WEPopover`from an `UIBarButtonItem` but from an `UIButton`, right?!
Just use

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect 
                    inView:(UIView *)view 
  permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections 
                  animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

instead of

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item 
           permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections 
                           animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

and pass in the rect of your `UIButton`.

Taking your code as an example:

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtnAccount:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.popoverController) {

        UIViewController *contentViewController = [[pageAccount alloc]initWithNibName:@"pageAccount" bundle:nil];
        self.popoverController = [[[popoverClass alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];
        self.popoverController.delegate = self;
        self.popoverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.navigationController.navigationBar];

        UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[senderButton frame]
                        inView:self.view
                                        permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown) 
                  animated:YES];

        [contentViewController release];
    } else {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popoverController = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanku for ur answer,but can you explain how to paass rect of my button?

Comment: -(IBAction)_clickbtnAccount:(id)sender
{
 if (!self.popoverController) {
  
  
  UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
  [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[senderButton frame]
            inView:@"pageAccount"
         permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown) 
             animated:YES];  
  
 } else {
  [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
  self.popoverController = nil;
 }
 
 
}

Comment: You have to pass an `UIView` (instead of @"pageAccount"), e.g. `self.view`.

Comment: Yes, the `....` indicated your original code that you didn't include in your updated question. I again modified my answer - give it a try.

Comment: ohh god ,again there in no button click event

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4001/discussion-between-tilo-and-nipinvarma)

Answer (score 0):

WEPopover is basically used to show multiple options inside a popover with much control using UITableview.

This is how i use WEPopOver to show popup on a button click

```
-(void)showPopOver:(id)sender{
    if (self.popoverController) {
            [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            self.popoverController = nil;
        } 
        PopOverTable *contentViewController = [[PopOverTable alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        contentViewController.delegatePopoverItemSelectedDelegate=self;
            rectForPopover = [self.view convertRect:btn.bounds fromView:btn];
                self.popoverController = [[[popoverClass alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];

                if ([self.popoverController respondsToSelector:@selector(setContainerViewProperties:)]) {
                    [self.popoverController setContainerViewProperties:[self improvedContainerViewProperties]];
                }
                self.popoverController.delegate = self;
                [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rectForPopover  
                                                        inView: self.view 
                                      permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny)
                                                      animated:YES];
        }
```

Comment: delegatePopoverItemSelectedDelegate: this is not a structure or union and rectforpopover undeclerd errors

Comment: dude..its my PopOverTable class's delegate. Use your own class delegate. Aren't you trying to show table inside a popOver?

Answer (score 0):

With the accepted solution I get rotation issues for the WEPopover under iOS 7: Basically it was pointing to a custom button in the UIBarButtonItem on the left of the navigation bar but on rotation the pop up moves to the right side of the screen and stays there on further rotations.